# How i solve memory leak problem?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I developing an simple application in which design or make code in which i creating and instance object of UIImage. When i swip on Ipad screen it make up an image of the sreen and that image i render into UIImage object after that this image i set into UIImageView object and UIimage object is released.
Every time i swipe on the screen and above process is does again and again. But it give me leak in `renderImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];`.

Code,

```
_renderImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

_textImageV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

[self renderIntoImage];

-(void)renderIntoImage
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bgTableView.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    _renderImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

 _textImageV.image = _renderImage;
[_renderImage release];
```

after completing the process of swipe i also releasing _textImageV.

How i solve the memory leak problem in UIImage *_renderImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
_renderImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns a new autoreleased `UIImage` and points the `_renderImage` ivar to it. The previously allocated `UIImage` is never actually released, the variable to it is just repointed to somewhere else.

This abandoned `UIImage` causes/is the memory leak. You should either release it before pointing `_renderImage` to something else, or you could just not allocate it in the first place.

Comment: how can we release it before assign it to something else?

Comment: Does this apply to ARC? If so, how do we release it?