# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() - Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am opening the camera with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` and a custom `cameraOverlayView` so I can take multiple photos without the "Use Photo" step.

This is working great, but there is a memory leak in the save photo function.  Through a lot of debugging and research I have narrowed it down to the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` function.

Here is a snippet of code where it happens:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(timestampedImage.frame.size, timestampedImage.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[[timestampedImage layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalTimestampImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I have scoured the internet and it seems that the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` function (quoted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498874/how-i-solve-memory-leak-problem)) *"returns a new autoreleased `UIImage` and points the `finalTimestampImage` ivar to it. The previously allocated `UIImage` is never actually released, the variable to it is just repointed to somewhere else."*

I've tried so many solutions that have apparently worked for others:

- Adding `timestampedImage.layer.contents = nil;` after `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`
- Adding `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` and `CGContextRelease(context);` after `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`
- Wrapping the above snippet in an `NSAutoreleasePool`
- Wrapping the entire `saveThisPhoto` function in an `NSAutoreleasePool`
- Creating an `NSAutoreleasePool` when the camera pops up and calling the `[pool release]` when `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called
- Closing the camera popup when `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called, hoping it will clear the pool
- Every possibly combination of the above

Yet everything I try, when I take photos I can see the `Memory Utilized` rising and not falling when I'm repeatedly taking photos on the device.

Does anyone know how I can release the autorelease object created by `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`?

Alternatively, is there an alternative way to make a `UIImage` out of an `UIImageView`?

**Edit:**

Here are the full functions as requested.  There's a lot of extra releasing added in there just to try make sure *everything* is cleaned up.  I have gone through and tested for the memory leak with each code block in `saveThisPhoto` systematically, and it only occurs when the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` block (snippet above) is run.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"SAVING PHOTO");

    [self saveThisPhoto:info];

    picker = nil;
    [picker release];

    info = nil;
    [info release];

}

- (void)saveThisPhoto:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // Get photo count for filename so we're not overriding photos

    int photoCount = 0;

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"photocount"]) {
        photoCount= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"photocount"] intValue];
        photoCount++;
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", photoCount] forKey:@"photocount"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Obtaining saving path

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ri_%d.jpg", photoCount];
    NSString *fileNameThumb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ri_%d_thumb.jpg", photoCount];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSString *imagePathThumb = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameThumb];

    // Extracting image from the picker and saving it

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    // SAVE TO IPAD AND DB

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){

        // Get Image

        UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        // Figure out image orientation

        CGSize resizedSize;
        CGSize thumbSize;

        if (editedImage.size.height > editedImage.size.width) {
            resizedSize = CGSizeMake(480, 640);
            thumbSize = CGSizeMake(150, 200);
        } else {
            resizedSize = CGSizeMake(640, 480);
            thumbSize = CGSizeMake(150, 113);
        }

        // MAKE NORMAL SIZE IMAGE

        UIImage *editedImageResized = [editedImage resizedImage:resizedSize interpolationQuality:0.8];

        // clean up the one we won't use any more

        editedImage = nil;
        [editedImage release];

        // ADD TIMESTAMP TO IMAGE

        // make the view

        UIImageView *timestampedImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:editedImageResized];
        CGRect thisRect = CGRectMake(editedImageResized.size.width - 510, editedImageResized.size.height - 30, 500, 20);

        // clean up

        editedImageResized = nil;
        [editedImageResized release];

        // make the label

        UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:thisRect];
        timeLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentRight;
        timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(25.0)];
        timeLabel.text = [self getTodaysDateDatabaseFormat];
        [timestampedImage addSubview:timeLabel];

        // clean up what we won't use any more

        timeLabel = nil;
        [timeLabel release];

        // make UIIMage out of the imageview -- MEMORY LEAK LOOKS LIKE IT IS IN THIS BLOCK

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(timestampedImage.frame.size, timestampedImage.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        [[timestampedImage layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *finalTimestampImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        timestampedImage.layer.contents = nil;
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextRelease(context);

        // clean up the one we won't use any more

        timestampedImage = nil;
        [timestampedImage release];

        // SAVE NORMAL SIZE IMAGE TO DOCUMENTS FOLDER

        NSData *webDataResized = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalTimestampImage, 1.0); // JPG

        [webDataResized writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

        // clean up the one we won't use any more

        finalTimestampImage = nil;
        [finalTimestampImage release];

        [pool release]; // to get rid of the context image that is stored

        // SAVE TO DATABASE

        [sqlite executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO inspection_images (agentid,groupid,inspectionid,areaid,filename,filenamethumb,filepath,orderid,type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?) ",
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:loggedIn],
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:loggedInGroup],
         myInspectionID,
         [[tableData objectAtIndex:alertDoMe] objectForKey:@"areaid"],
         fileName,
         fileNameThumb,
         documentsDirectory,
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:photoCount],
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:isPCR]
         ];

        // Clean up

        webDataResized = nil;
        [webDataResized release];

    } else {

        NSLog(@">>> IMAGE ***NOT*** SAVED");

    }

    NSLog(@"IMAGE SAVED - COMPLETE");

    info = nil;
    [info release];

}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the problem is not with further code that makes use of the `finalTimestampImage` image? Maybe there is a retain cycle somewhere.

Comment: `finalTimestampImage` is used to get a `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` which is saved to the device, then both of them are `released`.  I'm still convinced it is the sneaky `UIImage` the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` function creates as mentioned in the other SO question.

Comment: nope, you misunderstood the the previous SO question. "The previously allocated UIImage" is the UIImage in `_renderImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];` which leaks in `_renderImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`. If you declare the the variable like you do in your snippet it won't leak. Perhaps you could post a more complete code sample.

Comment: Thanks for having a look,  I have added full functions to the question above if you have time to have a look.  So you believe because I am getting the `UIImage` from the function like this `UIImage *finalTimestampImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` (as opposed to `alloc] init]` like in the other question) it shouldn't be leaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your variables to nil before releasing them, and some are already auto released.

Normally when using release you should release and them set to nil.

```
[var release]
var = nil;
```

But in some of these you should not be calling release.

The following one is your main culprit.

```
    // clean up the one we won't use any more

    timestampedImage = nil;
    [timestampedImage release];

    // SAVE NORMAL SIZE IMAGE TO DOCUMENTS FOLDER
```

Comment: Thanks for this, not sure how I messed up the nil/release order.  I am only releasing `timeLabel` and `timestampedImage` as they are the ones I manually `alloc`.  I can now repeatedly take photos without any leaks - just took 225 photos concurrently and could have kept going!  Many thanks again!

Comment: In iOS8, using ARC how to handle "UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()". Its always returning "nil".