# Memory issue with view snap shot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgimage, uigraphicscontext

When I get the snapshot of view using the below code, it allocates 12MB of memory again and again when I navigate to the view and get back to the previous view.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
 [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

While profiling using instruments, I get to know that CGRaster Data is responsible for this?
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to put you're code to `autoreleasepool`.

```
@autoreleasepool
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
   [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too. It doesn't work. I have return the image to another function. If I comment out the this part of code memory issue won't occur.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967460/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext-memory-leak Use this article pleas it seams to me you forgot to release and nil variable.

Comment: Found the issue. Issue is not with taking snapshot, i have scaled the image taken using imageWithCGimage:scale:orientation. After, I have changed the scaling function to another one memory have reduced significantly.